# How to Get Current And Previous Year Total Amount SUM In Postgres

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have a table like

| SR No | Name | Amount 1 | Amount 2 | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Crop1 | 1000 | 3000 | 2023 |
| 2 | Crop2 | 2000 | 1000 | 2023 |
| 3 | Crop3 | 5000 | 2500 | 2022 |
| 4 | Crop4 | 1500 | 3500 | 2022 |
| 5 | Crop5 | 3500 | 4500 | 2021 |
| 6 | Crop6 | 9500 | 4000 | 2021 |

Now, I want Result like

| Year | Year Sum | Previous year Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 3000 | 6000 |
| 2022 | 6000 | 8500 |
| 2021 | 8500 | 0 |

```
Explanation - Year 2023 -> Year Sum = total of Amount 1 of year 2023
              Year 2023 -> Previous Year Sum = total of amount 2 of year 2022
              Year 2022 -> Year Sum = total of Amount 2 of year 2022(Previous year total of year 2023 row)
              Year 2022 -> Previous Year Sum = total of Amount 2 of year 2021
              Year 2021 -> Year Sum = total of Amount 2 of year 2021(Previous year total of year 2022 row).
              Year 2021 -> Previous Year Sum = total of Amount 2 of year 2020.
```

I have tried using case when conditions but not getting proper result,

How to get result like this.

Comment: "Year 2023 -> Year Sum = total of Amount **1**" and "Year 2022 -> Year Sum = total of Amount **2**"  ??  Is this what you really want? or do you have a typo ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cte and window functions:

```
with sums as (select year, sum(amount1) sum1, sum(amount2) sum2
              from test group by year)
SELECT year, 
       case when (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY year desc) = 1) then sum1 else sum2 end as year_sum,
       COALESCE (LEAD(sum2,1) OVER (ORDER BY year DESC) , 0)  as previous_year_sum
FROM
    sums order by year desc;
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/10202)

Comment: Thanks @Turo, Great it's working for me, i got same result that i expect.

Answer (score 0):

When the "Year Sum" is the total of "Amount 1" (always), you can do:

```
SELECT
  Year,
  "Year Sum",
  COALESCE(Lag("Sum2") OVER (Order by Year),0) as "Previous year Sum"
FROM (
  SELECT
    Year,
    SUM(Amount_1) as "Year Sum",
    SUM(Amount_2) as "Sum2"
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY Year
)
ORDER BY Year dESC
```

output:

| year | Year Sum | Previous year Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 3000 | 6000 |
| 2022 | 6500 | 8500 |
| 2021 | 13000 | 0 |

First get the totals, then use `LAG()` to move the totals to the previous year.

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/8ZHIctdz)

Comment: Thanks @Luuk for your reply but i want result like previous year total is next year total.

Comment: Please explain. in your question, the differences between `Amount 1` and `Amount 2`. Like my comment (on the question) it is unclear, and because of being unclear result in answer might not be (totally) correct.

Comment: in first row Year Sum of current year total and "Previous year Sum" is Current - 1(2022) year total. In second row Year Sum is Previous year Sum of 2023 row and "Previous year Sum" is total of (2021)year

Comment: That is **not** an answer to "Please explain. in your question, the differences between `Amount 1` and `Amount 2`". when you want/need totals on `Amount 1` only, then please replace all occurrences of `Amount 2` with `Amount 1`.